# How to break else statement and exit the program

Tags: java

```
package oddsorevens;``                      
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class OddsOrEvens 
{

 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {

     Scanner name= new Scanner (System.in);   // getting input from user
     System.out.print("Hi! What's your name: ");
     String user = name.nextLine();    // getting user name
     System.out.println("Hello: "+user);
     System.out.println("Let's play OddsOrEvens");
     System.out.println("Choose Odd or Even");
     String s ="oddOrEven";
     Scanner str = new Scanner(System.in);   // getting new string from user
     String s1 = str.next();  //storing odd or even here
     o:
     if (s1.equals("even")||(s1.startsWith("e")))
     {
         System.out.println("You choose even");
         System.out.println("Computer choose odd");
     }
     else if (s1.equals("odd")||(s1.startsWith("o")))
     {
         System.out.println("You choose odd");
         System.out.println("Computer choose even");
     } 
     else
     {
          System.out.println("Entered wrong keyword"); 
     }    
     System.out.print("How many fingers you want to put out: ");
     Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
     int n=num.nextInt();
     Random rand = new Random();
     int computer = rand.nextInt(6);
     System.out.println("Computer choose "+ computer +" fingers");
     int sum;
     sum=n+computer;
     System.out.println(sum);
     if(sum%2==0)
     {
         System.out.println(sum+" is even");
     }
     else 
     {
         System.out.println(sum+" is odd");
     }
      int  u = s1.length();
          if(u/2==0)
          {
              System.out.println("You won :)");
          }
          else
          {``
              System.out.println("You lose :(");    
          }     
}



}
```

This is my first pgm in java. here if the user enter wrong keyword pgm should be break and based on the user input the output of the pgm will be win or lose. help please.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want your application to stop, you have to explicitly tell that you want to exit. To do so you have write just piece of line of code and that is `System.exit(0)`

Here sample code to understand it better:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
  if (s.next().equals("o")) {
    System.out.println("game is still on");
  } else {
    System.out.println("game end!");
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```